# Find only the matched pattern in a CSV file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I am trying to print only the matched pattern in a CSV file. Example: all the columns value starting with `35=its value`. Thanks.

CSV file:

```
35=A,D=35,C=129,ff=136
D=35,35=BCD,C=129,ff=136
900035=G,D=35,C=129,ff=136
35=EF,D=35,C=129,ff=136,35=G
36=o,D=35,k=1
```

Output:

```
35=A
35=BCD
35=EF
35=G
```

The command I used did not work:

```
sed -n '/35=[A-Z]*?/ s/.*\(35=[A-Z]*?\).*/\1/p' filename
```

Comment: try to remove space before s in sed expression. it might be difficult to catch both 35in third line.

Comment: Use the following: `sed -e 'y/,/\n/; /^35=/P; D' filename`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `GNU grep` which supports `-o` option to print only matched string, each on its own line

```
$ grep -oE '\b35=[^,]+' ip.csv 
35=A
35=BCD
35=EF
35=G
```

- `\b` is word boundary, so that `900035` won't match
- `[^,]+` to match one or more non`,` characters
- assumes the values do not contain `,`

With `awk`

```
$ awk -F, '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^35=/) print $i} }' ip.csv 
35=A
35=BCD
35=EF
35=G
```

- `-F,` set `,` as input field separator
- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` iterate over all fields
- `if($i~/^35=/)` if field starts with `35=`

  - `print $i` print that field

Similar with `perl`

```
perl -F, -lane 'foreach (@F){print if /^35=/}' ip.csv
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In Solaries the grep option o is not available. used the awk for the solution.

Comment: Note that `\b` isn't the best choice of boundary ; it would for instance match `35=value` from `somethingsomething, 42.35=value, somethingelse`. If the `grep` versions supports `-P`erl regex and the input contains no spaces, I'd use a lookbehind to assert that we match from the start of a field. If there can be extra spaces this would require variable-length lookbehinds, which aren't implemented in any regex flavour available to grep AFAIK.

Comment: @Aaron agreed.. steeldriver's solution based on csv module is most robust... for variable length lookbehinds `\K` can be used https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/639/lookahead-and-lookbehind/2462/simulating-variable-length-lookbehind-with-k#t=201706131404435949328

Comment: @Sundeep thanks for the `\K` trick, I knew about the meta-character but had never thought about its ability to emulate basic variable-length lookbehinds :)

Answer (score 14):

Using `tr` to replace all commas with newlines, and then `grep` to get all lines that start with the string `35=`:

```
$  tr ',' '\n' <data.in | grep '^35='
35=A
35=BCD
35=EF
35=G
```

Answer (score 6):

With perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'print for /(\b35=[^,]+)/g' filename
35=A
35=BCD
35=EF
35=G
```

or perhaps more generally/robustly using the [Text::CSV module](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm)

```
$ perl -MText::CSV -lne '
  BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new()} 
  print for grep { /^35=/ } $p->fields(), $p->parse($_)
' filename
35=A
35=BCD
35=EF
35=G
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl lookarounds with grep work really well.

`grep -oP '(?<=35\=).*?(?=,)'`

This returns the exact information minus the `35=` bit

`grep -oP '(?<=35\=).*?(?=,)' file.csv` will return this

> A
>   BCD
>   G
>   EF

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash solution:

```
(                                                  # Use parentheses as scope for IFS
    IFS=$',\n'                                     # Split on both , or \n
    for c in $(</tmp/file.csv)                     # For every column or row
    do
        [[ "$c" =~ ^35= ]] && echo ${line##35=}    # Find ^35= and print while removing ^35=
    done
) # Optionally >/tmp/filtered-output.txt
```

Note, **only use this for its readability and flexibility - if you can read it**, otherwise you can use the following approach:

```
# Read            | Replace     | Find        | Remove
cat /tmp/file.csv | tr ',' '\n' | grep '^35=' | sed 's/^35=//'
```

which is more intuitive and efficient.

Input (/tmp/file.csv):

```
35=A,D=35,C=129,ff=136
D=35,35=BCD,C=129,ff=136
900035=G,D=35,C=129,ff=136
35=EF,D=35,C=129,ff=136,35=G
36=o,D=35,k=1
```

Output:

```
A
BCD
EF
G
```